# iOS - How to add "Today Extension" target in Xcode 12.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widget, today-extension

I'm using Xcode 12.1 `12A7403`, and when I go to `Editor > Add Target`, the option to create "Today Extensions" using Storyboards no longer exists, but instead, there is only the option to create "Widget Extensions" using SwiftUI.

[image]

Is there a way to create "Today Extensions" in this version of Xcode? I still want my extension to be compatible with iOS 13.

Comment: Seems to be deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter

Comment: Solved by downgrading to Xcode 11.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an [Apple Systems Engineer of Apple's Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650350):

> Today Extensions continue to be available, however, they are deprecated. When your app is submitted for the newer SDK the legacy today widget extension will be removed.

That being said, widgets that were originally designed for earlier iOS versions are still available on device - just only in more limited capacity (app the bottom of Today View). According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/widgets/):

> Today widgets designed for iOS 13 and earlier aren’t available on the Home screen, but remain accessible at the bottom of the Today View and in the macOS Notification Center.

Edit: This means in order to create a Today Extension, one must downgrade to XCode 11, then create an target Today Extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw this too, but this only mentions Today View Extension's compatibility with higher iOS versions. It doesn't answer my question of how to add the extension target in Xcode 12.

Answer (score 5):

1. Download Xcode11
2. Create Today Extension
3. Coding in Xcode12
4. Release to App Store.

Worked for me.